# How to convert HTML file into Framemaker Interchange Format(.mif) file?

Tags: html, framemaker

- I want to mark index and cross-references like Framemaker does.
- Framemaker can export the .fm into .htm and .mif file.
- I have analyzed how the index and cross-references appears in .htm and .mif file after exporting it from framemaker.
- Now my system will produces .htm file and I can manage to mark the index and cross-reference like framemaker does.
- I want that framemaker retain the index and cross-references which will be marked by my system.
- But there is no way to import or open HTML files directly in Framemaker.
- We can import .mif file in framemaker.
- So is there any way we can convert HTML files into .mif(FrameMaker Interchange Format).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is one option, I know its not full proof solution for this problem.
but it can save your efforts to some point,

1. Save the HTML file to RTF format (using MS word/Open Office)
2. Open that RTF file in FM
3. FM accepts the RTF file and convert it into .fm file
4. Save the .fm file into .mif format

**Note :  in this conversion, some data loss may happen, i have tried using it for Markers it works but not complete solution.**

All the best!!

Answer (score 0):

You can open the .htm files in Structured FrameMaker and then save them to .mif. This will produce less loss in graphics, for sure.

Comment: Please expand your answer a bit. [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)